# How to perform conditional navigation depending on firebase authentication state in android

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

My launcher activity `MainActivity` hosts a bottom navigation. I want to check if the user is not logged in and then redirect him to `LoginFragment`. I'm stranded on how to check if there's a signed-in user in the `Mainactivity`. I'd be glad if you share some insight

Comment: if user == null, do something, else, do something, i'd guess

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44583834/firebase-how-to-check-if-user-is-logged-in

Answer (score 0):

You can store the user login status in shared preference when  user is logged in first time. Please write below this code in the onCreate() method your MainActivity to check whether user is logged in or not at the time of app opening.

```
val graph = navController.navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.mobile_navigation)

    if (PrefUtils.with(this).getBoolean(PrefKey.KEY_IS_LOGGOD_IN, false)) {

        bottomNavView.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        graph.startDestination = R.id.navigation_home

    } else {

        bottomNavView.visibility = View.GONE
        graph.startDestination = R.id.loginFragment

    }
    navController.graph = graph
```

Here if a user is already logged in go to home UI otherwise  login UI